# Podio .NET View.Items always returns zero

Tags: podio

Using the Podio.NET library (Podio.Async), I am trying to get a Podio View object using the `ViewService.GetView()` method. The Podio View object represents a predefined view, or set of filters, within a Podio Application.

One of the properties of the Podio View object (`PodioAPI.Models.View`) is the `Items` property, as in `var noOfItems = myView.Items`. However, this field always seems to return zero for me.

I guess that I can make a call to `ItemService.FilterItemsByView()` using the view-id, which in turn returns a `PodioCollection<Item>` object that has a `FilteredItems` property that can be used to get the number of items, but this would mean an additional call.

Does anyone have any thoughts or information that may help me?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question, and I hope that you can help, or others find this helpful.

Kaine

*Example code*

```
    class Program
    {
        const string CLIENT_ID = "[Your Client Id]";
        const string CLIENT_SECRET = "[Your Client Secret]";
        const int APP_ID = [Your App Id];
        const string APP_TOKEN = "[Your App Token]";
        const string VIEW_NAME = "[Your View Id]";


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => { await Go(); }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        static async Task Go()
        {
            var client = await GetClient();
            var views = await GetViews(client);
            var view = await GetView(client);
            var viewItems = await GetViewItems(client, view);
        }



        static async Task<View> GetView(Podio client)
        {
            var view = await client.ViewService.GetView(APP_ID, VIEW_NAME);
            Console.WriteLine("View Name: {0}, Id: {1}, Items: {2}",view.Name, view.ViewId, view.Items);
            return view;
        }


        static async Task<List<View>> GetViews(Podio client)
        {
            var views = await client.ViewService.GetViews(APP_ID);
            Console.WriteLine("Views: " + views.Count);
            foreach (var view in views)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" - ({0}) {1}", view.ViewId, view.Name);
            }
            return views;
        }


        static async Task<List<Item>> GetViewItems(Podio client, View view)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("View Items: " + view.Items);   // This always return 0
            var itemList = new List<Item>();
            var itemsRemaining = true;
            var offset = 0;
            while (itemsRemaining)
            {
                var colItems = await client.ItemService.FilterItemsByView(appId: APP_ID, viewId: Int32.Parse(view.ViewId), offset: offset);
                Console.WriteLine(" Downloaded: {0} to {1}", offset, offset + colItems.Items.Count());
                itemList.AddRange(colItems.Items);
                offset += colItems.Items.Count();

                if (offset >= colItems.Filtered)
                {
                    itemsRemaining = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total View Items Downloaded: " + itemList.Count);
            return itemList;
        }


        static async Task<Podio> GetClient()
        {
            var client = new Podio(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            var auth = await client.AuthenticateWithApp(APP_ID, APP_TOKEN);
            Console.WriteLine("Auth expires in: " + auth.ExpiresIn);
            return client;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add full example of code?

Comment: Hi @Pavlo-Podio , I have added the example code from a simple console app.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 similar methods:

**Get Views:** https://developers.podio.com/doc/views/get-views-27460
This method is returning `items` for each view returned

```
"items": The number of items matching the view
```

**Get View:** https://developers.podio.com/doc/views/get-view-27450
This method is not returning `items` parameter, but you can still get that from `groupings` param (if there is any grouping). Otherwise - number of items in view is not returned.

```
"groupings": individual groups data, if grouping is present, otherwise {}
    {
      "total": total count of items in all groups,
      "groups": [{
        "count": items count of the single group,
```

In case if there are no groupings you'll have to call https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-by-view-4540284. And then use `filtered` response value.

```
 "filtered": Total number of items matching the filter,
```

If you only need number of filtered items - please add `limit=1` parameter to your request.

Comment: Thanks for your response Pavlo-Podio. Having used the `get-view-27450` call in the *Sandbox*, I don't seem to get anything from `groupings` field, see screenshot ![link to screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/WsTvlfaRb2r)

Also, I am accessing this property via the .NET framework, rather than making the REST API calls.

Comment: .Net framework is using REST API call, so if data is not returned from API then it won't be available. Also, if there are no groupings then number of items won't be returned, so you'll have to call either get-all-views or filter items by view

Comment: Thanks you Pavlo-Podio. It seems a shame that the view cannot carry the number of matching items without using groups. I appreciate your help though. Thanks again.